# loadUrl does not work in real devices

Tags: android

In my Android application I created help activity that displays html with simple text. I call the html as below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.helpView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");
}
```

It works fine in simulators but does not work on real devices, there I get error: "webpage not available." (I tried 2 simulators and 2 devices.) Is anyone can advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `WebChromeClient` and set `setWebViewClient` add only

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YourWebView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your.html");
```

And also add `INTERNET permission` into `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have this permission in the manifest. This is not a problem.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I also do not use javascript there. It is very simple text representation.

Comment: then you first remove u r `webchromeclint` and let me know and also remove `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Comment: I changed setWebChromeClient to setWebViewClient and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.helpView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
  {  
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
  }  
}); 
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");
```

Comment: I changed setWebChromeClient to setWebViewClient in my code and it works now.